# Vertical scrolling of panel doesn't work java

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, vertical-scrolling

So I'm making a program as a project for school.
In this program I have a panel inside a scrollpane.
When I click a button a panel with info is added to the panel inside the scrollpane.
I can keep adding as much of these panels as I want.

I set the layout of the panel to FlowLayout.
I disabled the horizontal scrolling and set the width of the panel to the width of the scrollpane so I neatly get two of those 'forms' next to each other before it starts a new row of panels.
Problem is the vertical scrolling doesn't activate so I can see only 1,5 rows of panels. (see picture)

http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a518/Bas_Van_den_Steen/Screenshot2014-05-22191813_zps44483b9b.png

I suspect this has something to do with the height of the main panel I had to define if I wanted to set a width.
Ideally there should be an option to set the height to 'automatic', but there isn't.

I know scrolling works because when I enable horizontal scrolling and don't set any dimensions for the panel it just keeps adding forms in a single row which I can scroll through.

I think I might need to use another LayoutManager (but I don't have any experience setting those up) or change some of the settings of the scrollpane or main panel.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What did you set the height of the main panel to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the width of the panel to the width of the scrollpane so I neatly get two of those 'forms' next to each other before it starts a new row of panels. Problem is the vertical scrolling doesn't activate

A `FlowLayout` is designed to display components horizontally and the preferred size is always based on a single row of components.

Use a different layout manager. Maybe a `vertical BoxLayout`, or `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout` depending on your exact requirement.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information and working examples.

> set the width of the panel to the width of the scrollpane

You should not be manually setting the preferred width of you panel. As I mentioned earlier that is the job of the layout manager. Maybe the GridLayout is closes to what you need.